# Object object error when trying to save to local storage and display

Tags: javascript, object, output, stringify

Been trying to work out why I keep getting an output of [Object, object] instead of what the key is being saved as in local storage.

The function is meant to add a new body of text to a site and keep it there in local storage when the page is refreshed.

```
function saveEntry() {
    console.log("saveEntry called with variables in scope:", {
            key,
            initialText,
            isNewEntry,
            textareaElement,
    });

    var data = text;
        var item = makeItem("text", data);
        localStorage.setItem(key, item);
        console.log("saved item", key, "=", textareaElement.value);
    }

    textareaElement.addEventListener("change", saveEntry); 
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `[Object object]` instead of `[Output output]`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, Object object was what I meant. It is very early/late here and my brain is at half output lol.

Comment: I am still struggling with the object outputs. Any guidance would be great. Very new to JS.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the question that closed this thread (there's a link above your question). There are also great resources over at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). You can only store strings, so you have to convert your object to a string when saving, and then back into an object when reading.